# How to decode utf-7 in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, utf-7

Windows Phone 8 does not support UTF-7. Is there any way to decode UTF-7 like in the following .NET code?

```cs
Encoding.UTF7.GetString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting Windows Phone 8.1, you can use the WinRT method

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-7").GetString(...);
```

The complete list of encoding identifiers that can be passed to this method is listed [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (scroll down to the *Remarks* section).

When using Windows Phone 8.0 (Phone Silverlight), as far as I know this is not possible. The [System.Text.Encoding MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a3kf7c%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) lists only UTF-8 and UTF-16 as supported encodings.